# javax regex validation of path variables in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator, javax.validation

I have validation working for the beans and request parameters, however, my path variables fail to get validated:

`@PathVariable @Pattern(regexp = "[A-Za-z0-9]+") String protocol`

When I provide path var as `ab!ab` it doesn't fail the request with 400 status code but lets it pass with the value assigned to the argument.

I have also validated my regex online and it is valid and should be working fine.

Also, my rest controller does have `@Validated` annotation.

What am I missing here?

================UPDATE=============

I have tried other constraint annotations and none of them work, so it must something to do with the path variable validation. But what??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have

> hibernate-validator

dependency and add following bean:

```
@Bean
public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
    return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
}
```

Comment: For anyone else that are also new to this. I inserted the Bean in the class with the @SpringBootApplication annotation (where your main method is declared). If any of you proos out there know of a better place I am all ears. But it worked like a charm!

Comment: @W_O_L_F you could simply create a config class annotated with `@Configuration` annotation and put it there.

Comment: it's not working, I've tried but the behavior was the same.